# passing 2D arrays into constructor

Tags: java, arrays

can you please give me the idea how to pass 2D arrays into the constructor.i have passed the arrays with values but iam getting wrong answer.here with iam sharing my code.

```
    package payroll;
    import java.util.Scanner; 
    import javax.swing.*;

    class Payroll
    {
     private String empID;   
     private String empName;
     private int numOfHours;
     private double hourlyRate;
     private double totalPay;

     public Payroll(){}

     public Payroll(Object[][]emp, int scale)
     {
      for(int k=0;k<emp.length;k++)
      {
         this.empID = emp[k][l].toString();
         this.empName = emp[k][l].toString();
         this.numOfHours = Integer.parseInt(emp[k][l].toString()); 
         this.hourlyRate = Integer.parseInt(emp[k][l].toString());
       }
  }
 }

     public String getID()
     {
     return empID;
     }
     public String getName()
     {
     return empName;
     }
     public int getNumOfHours()
     {
     return numOfHours;
     }
     public double getHourlyRate()
     {
     return hourlyRate;
     }

     public double gettoTotalPay()
     {
     return numOfHours * hourlyRate;
     }

    }


    class Employer{
             public static void main(String [] args)
      {
            String empId; 
            String empName;
            String numOfHrs;
            String hourlyRate;
            Payroll emp1 = new Payroll();
            Object [][]emp = new Object[1][1];


           Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    for(int i=0;i<emp.length;i++)
      {   // start for loop
         for(int j=0;j<emp[0].length;j++)
            {  
             emp[i][j]= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Employer ID");
               if ( (emp[i][j].equals(""))) 
                 {
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null,"Employee ID Not Correct");
             emp[i][j]= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Employer ID");       
                }
            emp[i][j] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Employer Name");
            if(emp[i][j] == null )
                    {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Employee Name Cannot Be Empty");
            emp[i][j] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Employer Name");
                    }
            emp[i][j] =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Number of Hours Worked on");
            if(emp[i][j] == null )           
            {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Number of Hour Cannot be empty or more than 8");
            emp[i][j] =  Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Number of Hours Worked on"));
            }
            emp[i][j] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Hourly Rate ");             
            if(emp[i][j] == null)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Number of Hourly Rate Cannot be empty or Minus Value");
                hourlyRate = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Hourly Rate ");                

                    } 
         emp1 = new Payroll(emp,6 ); // this is the 2D array pass to Payroll Class
                   }//end inner for loop 
       }//end for loop          

      System.out.println("Employee Id:" +emp1.getID() );
      System.out.println("Employee Name:" +emp1.getName() );
      System.out.println("Employee Hours:" +emp1.getNumOfHours());
      System.out.println("Employee Total Payment:" +emp1.gettoTotalPay() );

      }
}
```

is if i insert the

```
employe id:1
emaployee name : asd
employee num of hrs:1
employee hourly rate :100
```

but answer getting

```
Employee Id:1
Employee Name:1
Employee Hours:1
Employee Total Payment:1.0
```

please  need advice

Comment: Aside from anything else, it sounds like you should be creating an `Employee` class with id, name, hours and rate...

Comment: As for the problem you're seeing: "i have passed the arrays with values" - no, you've passed an array with *one* value, 1. Look at the loop you've got in your `Payroll` constructor - you're using the same value for all 4 fields...

Comment: but i have use to this method to pass different data type into the arrays. Object [][]emp = new Object[1][1]; and i have passes in this way  emp1 = new Payroll(emp,6 );

Comment: *Why* do you have to use that method rather than using proper OO design? And how do you expect an `Object[1][1]` to contain 4 values?

Comment: object[1][4] = 1 row and inside the column has 4 different data types values

Comment: How do you expect that to work when you've created the array with `Object [][]emp = new Object[1][1]`? Just look at your code *carefully*.

Comment: but if i intialize the Object [][]emp = new Object[1][4] and data insertion time it is getting null pointer exception

Comment: So you're initializing it incorrectly. The right solution to that is to look carefully at what's going on - not trying to shove 4 values into a single array element...

Comment: so my goal is to 1 employee and find the gross pays.therefor i initialize the object size 1- employee1 and 4 mean number of fields .isnt it incorrect?

Comment: Right, but you don't *have* an `Object[1][4]` at the moment - you have an `Object[1][1]`. So fix that, then deal with the next error. You've got a *fundamental* problem here which you seem to be ignoring.

Comment: yes i have changed object size [1][4] but unfortunatly iam getting error while data insertion after null pointer exception

Comment: @nuke_infer Just a little modification is required.

Comment: @nuke_infer You are getting null pointer exception because you are not going to the next column.

Comment: @nuke_infer and this can only be achieved by incrementing j.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the inner for loop and add

```
++j;
```

3 times in the Employer class.

Now it is working fine.The reason you are getting the nullPointerException as u mentioned in your comments is because you are not going to next columns, you are staying in column 0, for that you have to  increment j

```
    import java.util.Scanner; 
    import javax.swing.*;
    class Employer{
             public static void main(String [] args)
      {
            String empId; 
            String empName;
            String numOfHrs;
            String hourlyRate;
            Payroll emp1 = new Payroll();
            Object [][]emp = new Object[3][4];
           Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    for(int i=0;i<emp.length;i++)
      {   // start for loop
            int j=0;  
             emp[i][j]= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Employer ID");
               if ( (emp[i][j].equals(""))) 
                 {
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null,"Employee ID Not Correct");
             emp[i][j]= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Employer ID");       
                }
                ++j;
            emp[i][j] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Employer Name");
            if(emp[i][j] == null )
                    {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Employee Name Cannot Be Empty");
            emp[i][j] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Employer Name");
                    }
                ++j;    
            emp[i][j] =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Number of Hours Worked on");
            if(emp[i][j] == null )           
            {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Number of Hour Cannot be empty or more than 8");
            emp[i][j] =  Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Number of Hours Worked on"));
            }
                ++j;
            emp[i][j] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Hourly Rate ");             
            if(emp[i][j] == null)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Number of Hourly Rate Cannot be empty or Minus Value");
                hourlyRate = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Hourly Rate ");                

                } 
         emp1 = new Payroll(emp,i ); // this is the 2D array pass to Payroll Class
                   //end inner for loop 
       }//end for loop          
      for(int i=0;i<emp.length;i++)
      {
       System.out.println("Employee Id:" +emp1.getID() );
       System.out.println("Employee Name:" +emp1.getName() );
       System.out.println("Employee Hours:" +emp1.getNumOfHours());
       System.out.println("Employee Total Payment:" +emp1.gettoTotalPay() );
      }

      }
}
    class Payroll
    {
     private String empID;   
     private String empName;
     private int numOfHours;
     private double hourlyRate;
     private double totalPay;

     public Payroll(){}

     public Payroll(Object[][]emp, int scale)
     {

      for(int k=0;k<=scale;k++)
      {
          int l=0;
         this.empID = emp[k][l++].toString();
         this.empName = emp[k][l++].toString();
         this.numOfHours = Integer.parseInt(emp[k][l++].toString()); 
         this.hourlyRate = Float.parseFloat(emp[k][l++].toString());
       }
  }


     public String getID()
     {
     return empID;
     }
     public String getName()
     {
     return empName;
     }
     public int getNumOfHours()
     {
     return numOfHours;
     }
     public double getHourlyRate()
     {
     return hourlyRate;
     }

     public double gettoTotalPay()
     {
     return numOfHours * hourlyRate;
     }

    }
```

Comment: but in here when iam inserting the employer name it is getting number format exception

Comment: yes i did frend.but it is getting number format exception after inserting the data it is showing the employee name like this  at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)

Comment: @nuke_infer But it is working fine in my case. Are you sure that you did not modify anything in the code of my answer.

Comment: no frend.i didnt modify anything your code.i am confused

Comment: @nuke_infer Does the error come exactly after entering the name?

Comment: @nuke_infer Got it, u must be specifying integer for hourly rate.

Comment: finally i solved and thank you very much frend and all of you . but i need to iterate this for 3 employers gross pay.how to iterate it.

Comment: i have change the array size like Object [][]emp = new Object[3][4] but now it is getting arrayout of bound exception

Comment: @nuke_infer I think the error was we had to use Float.parseFloat instead of Integer.parseInt

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83444/discussion-between-nuke-infer-and-dante).

Answer (score 0):

```
public Payroll(Object[][]emp, int scale)
 {
  for(int k=0;k<emp.length;k++)
  {
     this.empID = emp[k][l].toString();
     this.empName = emp[k][l].toString();
     this.numOfHours = Integer.parseInt(emp[k][l].toString()); 
     this.hourlyRate = Integer.parseInt(emp[k][l].toString());
   }
```

I Think you are not incrementing valraible l inside the loop. can you replace it with l++. Try and let me know....